# Cisco 3750 Interface Undersized Packet

Tags: networking

On one of our Cisco 3750 switch, i've found there is a continuous growing of undersized packet on 1 particular interface.

I don't understand exactly what's causing this undersized packet. But occasionally, maybe around twice a week, that this interface appears to have a large number of drop packets. I can't tell exactly if the drop packets is caused by the undersized packet though...   hope someone can point me to a right direction.

Here is the configuration of the interface:

> interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
>
> description WLC
>
> switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
>
> switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,10,100
>
> switchport trunk allowed vlan add 800,801
>
> switchport mode trunk
>
> srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
>
> srr-queue bandwidth shape 10 0 0 0
>
> queue-set 2
>
> mls qos trust cos
>
> auto qos voip trust
>
> no mdix auto
>
> storm-control broadcast level 1.00
>
> storm-control multicast level 1.00
>
> spanning-tree portfast
>
> spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
>
> spanning-tree bpduguard enable
>
> spanning-tree guard loop

thanks

SC

Answer (score 1):

An undersized packet would most likely be caused by a downstream device.

Trying moving whatever is plugged into that port to another port and see if the problem follows. If it does, check your cabling and the configuration or health of whatever is downstream of that port.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. And i did the following - changed another cable , and even changed to another interface. But i can still observe the undersized packet.  The device that the interface connected to is a Cisco wifi controller... i guess the problem is with the wifi controller then.   do you think the undersized packet could cause occasionally packet drop on the interface?

Comment: @SunCleverland I wouldn't immediately see a connection between an undersized packet and packet drop, but it's likely they're related symptoms. Seeing as the problem moved to another switch port, it's still safe to say it's caused by an issue with the downstream device.